# Using special JDBC driver features with dynamic proxy connection pools

Tags: java, jdbc, casting, connection-pooling

We are evaluating a JTA transaction manager for a legacy Oracle JDBC project and have looked at Bitronix and Atomikos so far.

The java.sql.DataSource implementations of both the Bitronix and Atomikos connection pools are making heavy use of dynamic proxy objects for the JDBC interface instances they return.

The PreparedStatements of the Bitronix PoolingDataSource connections are themselfs dynamic proxy objects, casting them to oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement results in a ClassCastException.
The Atomikos dynamic connection proxy objects on the other hand return actual OraclePreparedStatement instances - casting possible.

The legacy code uses [Oracle JDBC update batching](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraperf.htm#i1058859) and hence casts java.sql.PreparedStatements to oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement for calling OraclePreparedStatement.setExecuteBatch(batchSize).
Switching to standard JDBC batching is not an option.

How are we supposed to use special JDBC driver features that require access to the actual driver classes/interfaces in the given situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connection pools support the `java.sql.Wrapper` interface properly, you can get access to the wrapped object using the `unwrap` method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that indeed worked for both Bitronix 2.1.2 and Atomikos 3.7.0 - assuming the JDK6 Oracle driver of cause.

I had tested `unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement.class)` before, since oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement is the interface for the driver's PreparedStatement classes. I got a "*bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.JdbcUncachedPreparedStatementHandle is not a wrapper for interface oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement*" SQLException though.
Looking at the source of the Bitronix proxy class (JdbcUncachedPreparedStatementHandle) I found:

```
public Object unwrap(Class iface) throws SQLException {
    if (PreparedStatement.class.equals(iface)) {
        return delegate;
    }
    throw new SQLException(getClass().getName() + " is not a wrapper for interface " + iface.getName());
}
```

Wouldn't that rather have to be

```
public Object unwrap(Class iface) throws SQLException {
    if (iface.isAssignableFrom(delegate.getClass()) {
        return delegate;
    }
    throw new SQLException(getClass().getName() + " is not a wrapper for interface " + iface.getName());
}
```

?

Anyway - when I use this code it works for both Bitronix and Atomikos -  Atomikos not being an issue anyway since the returned PreparedStatement is not a proxy object as mentioned above.

```
((OraclePreparedStatement)pstmt.unwrap(PreparedStatement.class)).setExecuteBatch(100);
```

Comment: I've opened https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/BTM-114 to track this, and is now fixed. Thanks for pointing this out although it would have been more efficient to report the problem directly on the BTM mailing list.